# Difference between Higgs mechanism and Higgs decay

Tags: standard-model, definition, higgs

What is the difference between Higgs Mechanism and Higgs decay?

I know that [Higgs mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_mechanism) is a process which provide the mass to gauge boson.
In general, many literature explain Higgs mechanism via SSB (Spontaneous symmetry breaking), even though, we can explain Higgs Mechanism without SSB. [see [Higgs](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9295/), for reference].

In many case, I heard lots of Higgs Mechanism and Higgs decay frequently, indiscriminately.

In this question I want to know the exact terminology of above things and difference between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Higgs mechanism is a theoretical formulation answering how a gauge boson may acquire a mass.

The Higgs mechanism predicts the existence of a particle, called the Higgs boson.

Particles may decay, for example the neutron decays into a proton, electron and a neutrino.  Similarly the Higgs boson can decay.  Its decay into two photons was the discovery method at the LHC.  A Higgs decay is the decay of a Higgs boson.  The Higgs boson has numerous other decay channels.

Comment: just a precision: the Higgs discovery was made in both Higgs decaying into 2 photons and Higgs decaying into $ZZ^*\to 4$ leptons (the 2 channels were needed to claim a discovery + a small contribution from $H\to WW$)